# Combine wrapping and parent element in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have a specificity issue where styles from a CSS library are overwriting my SASS styles.

My HTML is:

```
<form class="some-library-class my-form-class">
  <input type="text" class="my-form-class__text">
```

My SASS is:

```
.my-form-class {
  //Some wrapper stlyes

  &__text {
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}
```

However, the library overwrites my style with:

```
.some-library-class input[type=text] {
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

Before I go and add extra wrapping classes to my neat SASS and creating too much depth, or start using `!important;` I wanted to see if there was a way I could modify my existing SASS so the CSS returned is:

```
.my-form-class .my-form-class__text {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Is there a neat SASS way to achieve the above without messing up my existing SASS too much?

Comment: I believe you don't want to edit the CSS library right? How about adding `form` in your SASS making it `form.my-form-class .my-form-class__text` so they have equal specificity? Then whichever comes later will be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.my-form-class {
  //Some wrapper stlyes

  & &__text {
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}
```

generates

```
.my-form-class .my-form-class__text {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```